# Choropleth map with dynamically data in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, choropleth

I am struggling with Javascript and Leaflet tryind to realize a dashboard.
I am trying to realize a choropleth map following this [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html).
I need to change dynamically data display on map according to two select menu.

Selects:

```
<select class="c-select" id="methodSelected" name="methodSelected" required>
</select>
<select class="c-select" id="yearSelected" name="yearSelected" required>
</select>
```

I am holding changing on selects with

```
$("#methodSelected").change()
$("#yearSelected").change()
```

both are declared inside a

```
$(document).ready(function() {}
```

In this block I also declare the required variables and functions

```
var choroplethMap;
var q = d3_queue.queue();
q.defer(d3.json, "final2.geojson");
function ready(GeoJSON) {
    ...
    makePlaceHolderChoroplethMap();
}
```

`makePlaceHolderChoroplethMap` is like that

```
function makePlaceHolderChoroplethMap() {
    choroplethMap = L.map('choroplethContainer').setView([51.505, -0.09], 2);
    L.tileLayer("url", 
       {
            id: id,
            attribution: attribution,
            accessToken: accessToken
        }
    ).addTo(choroplethMap);
```

Now when I will change values with the two select menu I want update map, so I put into `$("#yearSelected").change()` a call to `makeChoroplethMap()`.

```
function makeChoroplethMap() {}
```

Inside this function I put code following tutorial previously linked.

The problem is that when I changed the values with that code I will re-add new layers over others previously added (Geojson, legend and control, as you can see)

[image]

So I tryed to leave only binding with data into `makeChoroplethMap()`,

```
geojson = L.geoJson(data, 
    {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }
).addTo(choroplethMap);
```

but I recieve an error in `info.addTo(choroplethMap);` as `t is undefined`. I think because `choroplethMap` is not initialized. Map and select work, but controls are not displayed 'cause of error.
For now (I think I breaked something because yesteday worked) also geojson layer overstay over country also if I change values with select (the previously one putted does not go off also I change values).

So my question is: how can re-bind data without re-adding also legend and other control?

Comment: can we see this in a jsfiddle or standalone demo site?

Comment: I am trying to make it working on jsfiddle, but without success. I can provide you a demo that you can run local. Can be ok?

Comment: [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxzhljsVh6zoTTZvdXlxRWtiZDg)

Comment: Your first immediate problem is that you are trying to load a 66.4 meg geojson file into the browser. This needs to be simplified and probably divided into some form that a browser can actually digest and not blow up on... Do you have a database backing this app which can provide this data piecemealed as needed?

Comment: Yeah, I know, it is huge. I followed this [guide](http://georgiawildlife.com/node/2849) to integrate [shapefile](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/) and my data.json. In this way I took this geojson file. I need all the data that are in data.json. Actually I am only retrieving data.json from a database (with MongoDB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the legend and the GeoJSON layer **once**, when you're initializing the map. If you add them in `makeChoroplethMap`, you'll be **re-** adding them.

Then, use [`L.GeoJSON.clearLayers()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-clearlayers) and the
[currently undocumented `L.GeoJSON.addData()`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4642) method to clear/add polygons.

Comment: Seems that actually work. I am so frustrated about that, I tried to find somehow add data after initializing all day long and I cannot see that `addData()` is also [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html). Thanks mate.